# Integrate slick-slider into Wordpress, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I am quite new to .js and now I am trying to integrate a .js slider into Wordpress.vI am trying to get Slick-Slider working on a website. It works perfectly fine on my static webpage, but as soon as I tried to migrate it to Wordpress, I just can't get it to work. Not sure if it is a conflict within Wordpress or if I am doing something wrong. This is how I registered my js and css files in my functions.php – in the browser there are no errors showing up.

```
function mytheme_files() {

wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_theme_file_uri('/css/styles.css'));   
wp_enqueue_style('slick-css', get_theme_file_uri('/slick/slick.css'));   

wp_register_script('jquery', '//https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js', NULL, '3.5.1', true);  
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_migrate', get_theme_file_uri('//https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.1.min.js'), array(), NULL, true); 

    wp_enqueue_script('slick-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );   
    wp_enqueue_script('val-slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/val-slider.js', array(), NULL, true ) ; 


wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), NULL, true ) ; 
       
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_files');

?>
```

And in a separate js file I tried to register the slider with this code:

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {
$('.slideshow').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow:1,
    slidesToScroll: 10
});
```

I would be helpful for any advice!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple things to try.

First, make sure to set your custom js file to have 'slick-js' as a dependancy. This way it loads *after* slick slider does.

Also, jquery is already part of wordpress, so you **do not** need to enque it again. However, it should be a dependancy for both your custom script and slick:

```
wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('slick-js', 'jquery'), NULL, true ) ;
```

Second, I'm not sure what val-slider is, but it could be conflicting with slick slider. I suggest only using one javascript slider for your theme. Slick is very powerful and customizable, so It's a good choice.

Third, slick slider typically also has a theme-styles.css file that you should include. This pretties up the slider and puts arrows/dots in the right place.

Fourth, I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but make sure the div with class `.slideshow` is the immediate parent to your slides (typically a for or foreach loop.) If there is another surrounding div in there then slick will interpret that as one slide. Here's an example:

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <?php
   foreach($slides as $slide) {
     echo '<div class="slide">'; //this class name is unimportant
        //slide content here
     echo '</div>';
   };
   ?>
</div>
```

Fifth, not sure if this is a copy/paste error but you're missing the closing `)};` in your javascript.

Last thing, this wont break slick slider, but it could cause some weird things to happen; you have `slidesToScroll: 10` but are only showing one slide `slidesToShow:1`. I think it's a good practice to make these numbers the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, now it finally works. One other thing that I that I was not aware of, was that I was to replace the $ with jQuery, so my custom.js looks like this:

```
    `jQuery('.slider').slick({
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1, 
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: false,
          focusOnSelect: false,

  });`
```

Now it is finally running